# Laravel : ensure user can only be logged in on one computer at a time

Tags: php, security, laravel, laravel-4

I want to ensure that the users can't share the same login/password.

To do this, when a user try to log in i want to check if he is not already connected on a different computer.

My first idea is get all the users having actives sessions, but i don't know how ?
Or may be there is a better way ?

Comment: You could put a flag in your database when a user is logged in and check it before the user logs in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more things in here:

- ensuring that the users don't share the same credentials can be done
  through simple validation
- checking if user is already logged in can
  also be done through session - with login,logout methods that the user   will trigger.

You, as developer have total power to manage users per session basis.
You can improve design with some events notification, but stateless nature of HTTP protocol gives you limited number of tools for user tracking (except Google machinery :))
What is happening on their local machines in different thing, and out of scope of Laravel app.